# What library or framework is recommended as middleware for IndexedDB?

Tags: indexeddb

I'm developing a solution that will persist data in the users browser, so, I started to search about the best fit/framework/library to manipulate IndexedDB data.

If you're going to recommend it, could you tell me:

- Why are you recommending it (performance, features, facilities)?
- How far have you been using it?
- What were your difficulties on it?
- What are the most coolest feature that you think there is on it?

I believe that these kind of answer will help not only me, but, most of developers that are going to use it as well.

Comment: Might be better ask at Software Recommendations since SO is not for recommendations

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, IndexedDB is the internal database inside the browser (Chrome, Firefox, etc) and it's used to save data to get a better performance while loading websites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those that also are looking for an advice, after researching to use in our architecture, we've studied these following frameworks:

[Dexie](http://dexie.org/) A open source project that contains many supports for IndexedDB, focusing in architectures that are using Asynchronous method, allowing the application more smooth.

In other hands we have:
[AlaSQL](http://alasql.org/) Another open source project that contains support to access IndexeDB using SQL to manage its entities. Differently than Dexie, AlaSQL allow use synchronous method that may result in locks according your implementation.